# Continuity of a function between metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I want to show:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A \subset X$ be a closed subset. Define $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ by
>   $$ f(x) = d(x,A) := \inf_{y\in A}d(x,y), \phantom{.} \forall x \in X.$$
>   Show that (a) $f$ is continuous and (b) $f(x) = 0$ if and only if $x\in A$.

This function is a little odd to me. By definition of continuity, $f: (X,d_{X}) \to (Y,d_{Y})$ is continuous at $x_{0} \in X$ if for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $d_{Y}(f(x),f(x_{0})) < \varepsilon$ when $d_{X}(x,x_{0}) < \delta$. I know these definitions but putting them altogether cohesively and coherently is my downfall. Tips, hints, solutions, and suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and $x, z\in X$, and $d(x,z) < \delta$. Then, since $A$ is closed, you know that the infimum in the function definition is actually achieved at some $y_0$ (for $x$ and $y_1$ for $z$).($d(x,y)$ is bounded below and continuous for fixed $x$ so it achieves its $\inf$ on the closed set $A$). WLOG assume $d(x,y_0) \ge d(z,y_1)$. (It is symmetric). Then

$$
\begin{align*}
|f(x) - f(z)| &= |d(x, y_0) - d(z, y_1)|\\
&\le |d(x,y_1) - d(z,y_1)| \;\;\; &\text{since}\ d(x,y_0)\ \text{is the inf}\\
& \le d(x,z) &\text{Reverse triangle inequality}\\
& < \delta
\end{align*}
$$

so take $\delta = \epsilon$ and you are done for continuity.

If $x\in A$ then it is clear that $d(x,A)=0$, otherwise, let $x\in A^c$. If $d(x,A) = 0$ then there is a sequence in $A$ that approaches $x$, so $x$ is in the closure of $A$. This implies that $x\in A$ since $A$ is closed which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Given, $\epsilon>0$ choose $$\delta = \mathrm{some\ function\ of\ } \epsilon,$$   Now suppose $\xi\in X$ is such that $d(\xi,x)<\delta$, then we have

$$f(\xi) \le \mathrm{some\ work\ here} \le f(x) + \epsilon$$ and

$$f(x) \le \mathrm{some\ more\ work\ here} \le f(\xi) + \epsilon$$ so

$$|f(x)-f(\xi)| \le \epsilon,$$ and $f$ is continuous.

You should notice that $Y$ is just $\mathbb{R}$ so we use the normal absolute value for the norm.